# speeding up dataframe processing by concomitant filtering on pandas joins

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have two dataframes, one is pretty big the other is really huge.

```
df1: "classid"(text), "c1" (numeric), "c2"(numeric)
df2: "classid"(text), "c3" (numeric), "c4"(numeric)
```

I want to filter df2 based on values on df1. In pseudocode one would formulate it like this:

```
df2[(df2.classid == df1.classid) & (df2.c3 < df1.c1) & (df2.c4 < df1.c2)]
```

Right now I do this by iterating rows in df1 and doing some 40k filter calls on df2, which is a 3mil rows table. Obviously it works too slow.

```
df = dataframe()
for row in df1:
    dft = df2[(df2.classid == row.classid) & (df2.c3 < row.c1) & (df2.c4 < row.c2)]
    df.add(dft)
```

I guess the best option is to make an inner join and then the (df2.c3 < df1.c1) & (df2.c4 < df1.c2) filtering but the problem is that the inner join would create a huge table, since classid are not indexes and not unique row identifiers. If filtering could be applied concomitantly that might just work. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry it's unclear to me what you're trying to do here, you want to filter df2 where it contains classid's that exist in df1, then you want only the values where df2.c3 is < df1.c1 and df2.c4 < df1.c2 correct? so what's wrong with your current boolean mask? Why are you trying to do this iteratively? This is not explained very well

Comment: @EdChum First because it does not work, the error is "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare". Second it does not make sense (to me) df2[(df2.classid == df1.classid) & (df2.c3 < df1.c1) & (df2.c4 < df1.c2)] is pseudocode, but in real filtering you need a scalar, you can't simply supply the Series object of another dataframe, plus things must be synchronised on rows. Do you have examples of this working?

Comment: You can supply series for comparison but it depends on what you're doing, you should just filter the df first and then you could iterate over the unique classid values and then drop the rows where the other 2 criteria are not satisfied

Comment: So does your df1 have unique row values? i.e. unique rows for each classid?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating should be the last resort, I'd  merge the other dfs columns c1 and c2 to df:

```
df = df.merge(df1, on='classid', how='left')
```

Then I would groupby the classid and then filter the rows like the following example:

```
In [95]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'classid':[0,0,1,1,1,2,2], 'c1':np.arange(7), 'c2':np.arange(7), 'c3':3, 'c4':4})
df
Out[95]:
   c1  c2  c3  c4  classid
0   0   0   3   4        0
1   1   1   3   4        0
2   2   2   3   4        1
3   3   3   3   4        1
4   4   4   3   4        1
5   5   5   3   4        2
6   6   6   3   4        2
In [100]:

df.groupby('classid').filter(lambda x: len( x[x['c3'] < x['c1']] & x[x['c4'] < x['c2']]  ) > 0)
Out[100]:
   c1  c2  c3  c4  classid
2   2   2   3   4        1
3   3   3   3   4        1
4   4   4   3   4        1
5   5   5   3   4        2
6   6   6   3   4        2
```

Comment: The filtering on groups is not what I need, but the merging is what i intended through "left inner join". The merged df should be filtered then like this df[(df['c3'] < df['c1']) & (df['c4'] < df['c2']) ]. And now we arrive at the core of my problem: the merged table is simply too large in terms of RAM, isn't it a way to perform filtering the same time with merging? This is how databases do, that is why you can have "join" and "where" in the same SQL statement.

Comment: Not built in I don't think, this method would be performant if the entire df could fit in memory there is nothing here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html that mentions what you want but this would be how I would do this

Comment: yea, you would not be able to do this on my tables, unless you can hack into a supercomputer

Comment: One option would be to this in chunks and write to csv or hdfs, so take so many rows perform the op and then serialise the data out

Comment: Yes. I also have to investigate the copy parameter in df.merge(). It is True by default, I just noticed.

Comment: That should be fine though because you're creating a new df